# Error in Xcode saying that my stored property is not initialized at super.init call

Tags: ios, swift, properties, initialization

What I am trying to do is pass in a random value on a separate view controller for my text property based upon which of four buttons is pressed. The compiler tells me that my text property is not initialized at the super.init call and I have tried inverting the order and combining the two initializers into the required init?. Also if there are any suggestions on a better way to change the text based upon which button is pressed please let me know. Thank you!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var text: String

@IBOutlet weak var successButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var workButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var relationshipsButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var brightenDayButton: UIButton!


// Initialize text property that will later be passed into the label on PageController

init(text: String) {
    self.text = text
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder) // error occurs here

}

func buttonPressed() -> String {
    switch self {
    case successButton.touchInside == true: text = successText
    case workButton.touchInside == true: text = workText
    case relationshipsButton.touchInside == true: text = relationshipText
    case brightenDayButton.touchInside == true: text = brightenDayText
    default: text = "Didn't work"
    }
    return text
}
```

Comment: You have to set `self.text` to something before you call `super.init(coder...)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually you use required initializers like this:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let text = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("text") as String

    self.init(text: text)
}
```

Are you sure you need that kind of initializer?

Comment: When I do that Xcode complains saying I set a property to itself. If I add a text parameter in the required init method it asks for another required init method that implements the fatalError. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Since `text` is a non-optional the easiest solution is

```
var text = ""
```

that initializes the property in the declaration line.

Comment: This solves this particular problem. But what if you add more members? What if you have complex types?

Comment: A possible alternative is lazy initializing.